# VS 2017 Developer - Unable to deploy reports to SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, deployment, visual-studio-2017, ssrs-2012

I have a bit of a weird situation when attempting to deploy reports from Visual Studio 2017 to SSRS2012.

Everything works: url, Report Builder, SSRS itself, and it worked when I used SSDT for SQL Server 2012 - that is: I could deploy reports and they were working as designed.

However, after "upgrading" to VS2017 deployment ends with familiar error:

`The specified report server URL http://SERVER_NAME/Reports_INSTANCE/ could not be found.`

And this is were I'm stumped, as all TargetServerURL boxes point to `http://SERVER_NAME/Reportserver_INSTANCE/`. Checked and re-checked. Changed that for every configuration that matters (added `Deploy` and made sure `Release` is correct as well).

I'm obviously missing something but not sure what and/or where. Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found out was quite simple: my PC became a complicated disaster. I had installed SSMS2012, SSMS2017, VS2015 Community, VS2017 15.0 Community, VS2017 15.9 Professional...

All those versions probably caused some sort of internal conflicts - especially since they inexplicably installed themselves as standalone, separate environments.

In addition VS2017 introduced changes to way Data Tools are installed and handled, and there were reports that it didn't work as designed, so maybe reason for that was not entirely my mess.

I didn't find the cause of my issues, but as I was due a replacement for my machine that suffered major mechanical failure, new computer when set up with newest versions - in correct installation order, as well - the tools worked without issues.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is too late but it might help others. I was getting the same error, as in:

> Could not connect to the report server http://myserver/reports_mydevreports.
>   Verify that the TargetServerURL is valid and that you have the correct permissions to connect to the report server.

It turns out for me there are two similar URLs:

```
1. http://myserver/reports_mydevreports
2. http://myserver/ReportServer_mydevreports
```

The first gives you the Report Manager homepage. Using this for deployment doesn't work.

The second gives you a directory structure for the reporting server. This is what you need to use for deployment.

Took me over a day to figure this out :-(

Comment: Not really an answer to my question. I know the feeling because this was my experience when I first tried that way, but it was back in 2015. This one is different - because as far as I knew, all was fine - all links are up, servers are up, but no joy on connecting from VS2017.